# Object local to a thread in multiprocessing.dummy.Pool

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I'm using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` to issue RESTful API calls in parallel.

For now the code looks like:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
def onecall(args):
    env = args[0]
    option = args[1]
    return env.call(option) # call() returns a list

def call_all():
    threadpool = Pool(processes=4)
    all_item = []
    for item in threadpool.imap_unordered(onecall, ((create_env(), x) for x in range(100))):
        all_item.extend(item)
    return all_item
```

In the code above, `env` object wraps a `requests.Session()` object and thus is in charge of maintaining connection session. The 100 tasks use 100 different `env` objects. Thus, each task just creates 1 connection, make 1 API call, and disconnect.

However, to enjoy the benefit of HTTP keep-alive, I want the 100 tasks to share 4 `env` objects (one object per thread) so each connection serves multiple API calls one-by-one. How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `threading.local` seems to work.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import threading

tlocal = threading.local()
def getEnv():
    try:
        return tlocal.env
    except AttributeError:
        tlocal.env = create_env()
    return tlocal.env

def onecall(args):
    option = args[0]
    return getEnv().call(option) # call() returns a list

def call_all():
    threadpool = Pool(processes=4)
    all_item = []
    for item in threadpool.imap_unordered(onecall, ((x,) for x in range(100))):
        all_item.extend(item)
    return all_item
```